# Symfony2 Backend?

Tags: symfony, crud

I am new to Symfony, please don't scold me about this question.

I read in a Symfony 1.4 book that there is a functionality of adding backends to your applications via doctrine:generate-admin or generate:app backend, implementing CRUD operations.

Now I wonder, is there anything similiar with Symfony2.0?

Basically I have an user management and a database in the background that I would love to have available for my Admin Users, but do I have to code it myself (i.e. securing the are /admin, creating templates, classes, methods etc. that fulfill this tasks) or can it be done more easy by using some kind of an already existing backend functionality?

Thanks!

EDIT: Also read there's a plugin called "Apostophe" - but isn't there anything included with SF2 or are there any preconfigured SF2 Versions that already come with Backend solutions?

Comment: I have to tell you. Apostrophe is symfony 1.x, and to my feelings deeply sucks.  Tried it.  Lost time and money with it.  I have to say that in my situation, mostly the "reimplemented routing" (not a good idea and the "bad part" for us) gave us loads of problems in our multi-lingual site.   For the admin part, in symfony2, you need to get around it, see other answers for paths.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's the [SonataAdminBundle](http://bundles.knplabs.org/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle) (and possibly a few more I haven't seen) that helps provide an admin system, however this area is still being worked on heavily by the Symfony2 community.

Lukas has put together a blog article on the current state of development of a Symfony2 CMF, with some rough timescales - [State of the Symfony2 CMF](http://pooteeweet.org/blog/0/2042#m2042)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes that helps. At least I am feeling much better to know I didn't miss anything. I'll read through Lukas article, thanks!

Comment: How do most people with it usually? Create their own custom backend page for editing users (i.e.)?

Comment: We've built our own up from scratch using a CMS template we designed earlier in the year. Started working towards simplifying it, rather than generating every page, however haven't spent that much time on it. Couldn't say about the rest of the community though!

Comment: At work we are the same way.  We've custom built our entire CRM on the symfony2 framework..  And Now, I'm doing the same think with my CRM and Client Area for my new company as well.

Comment: Also, look for: `FR3DLdapBundle` along with `FOSUserBundle`, and my all the time favourite for frontend code generation: `MopaBootstrapBundle` along with good `AsseticBundle` and `LESS` AND `Twitter Bootstrap` goodness.

Answer (score 2):

Also there is another bundle for managing the admin. You can take a look here http://knpbundles.com/cedriclombardot/AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle

Answer (score 1):

For "admin generation", Symfony2 is not yet with the code generation on that aspect. The base is VERY STRONG. Remember Symfony2 is still at 2.0 stage. (Not 2.1++ like symfony1).

If you want cut and paste code. Symfony2 is not exactly for that.

**DISCLAIMER**

I am more specialized in frontend than backend, but I got around stuff. But Thanks to Symfony2. I can be on both sides. So I speak from this context.

**CAVEATS**

What I call "good stuff".

- Only using ONE `{{ form_widget(form) }}` that [Symfony form documentation recommends](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) ... and not explictly cut and pasting from [the Twig tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html) that is /meant/ to show how to do theme... not to implement like it is shown.
- Thinnest controller methods possible
- ... out of scope of this post.

**SO**

My best advice is serious RTFM, a few times, with Symfony books. It is scary, but I am working with it since three months and re-reading a lot. Everytime I get excited with gems.

**ANSWER IN QUESTION**

My current choice of bundles is:

- `FR3DLdapBundle`, with FOSUserBundle
- `MopaBootstrapBundle` along with all code generated with HTML/CSS structure Twitter Bootstrap gives. (if you haven't heard of it, yet, where were you?)
- `AsseticBundle` with proper `{%- javascript %}` inclusion

And the rest is contextual.

**My READ and  RE-Read list**

A hidden gem and very helpful blog posts were for me from:

- [Problematic's blog post series "On a diet"](http://iamproblematic.com/putting-your-symfony2-controllers-on-a-diet-part-2/)
- [Matthias Noback](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/)
- [Liip Symfony2 tagged blog posts](http://rocketlab.liip.ch/search?query=symfony2), but mostly the [Table Inheritance topic](http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2012/03/27/table-inheritance-with-doctrine.html)
- and [CraftItOnline](http://www.craftitonline.com/2011/10/symfony2-event-manager-the-stand-alone-way/)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness there is a native way to generate CRUDs:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:crud
```

This command will ask to you some information, like the entity, if you want a write action, the configuration format or the base route prefix.

In my opinion this is the fastest and light way to quickly generate a controller to create, read, update or delete your entities, so it is good on simple projects or to code a basic CRUD inside a little Bundle.

Official documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html